# How to show errors for multiple object forms - Play Framework 2 with Java

Tags: java, forms, playframework-2.0

I’m having trouble displaying the errors of my form containing multiple objects of the class, in my case ProductMilestone.
Basically I’m showing a form with all the milestones in a table, displaying and updating works 
very well. As soon as I get an error my template can’t be displayed anymore with an
error "[IllegalStateException: No value]".
This is because an erroneous form doesn’t contain the values that are received from the Form.get()
Method, in my case it’s the MilestoneSet.
What can I do to make this work with the errors displayed?

The problem is the for-loop in the view:

View:

> ```
> @(milestoneFormSet: Form[ProductMilestone.MilestoneSet], productReleaseId: Long)
>     @*Function called by the for loop in the form just below*@
>     @milestoneFields(milestone: ProductMilestone, index: Integer) = {
>         //…other fields
>         @inputText(milestoneFormSet("milestoneList[" + index + "].initialDate"),  '_label -> "",'class -> "datepicker")   
>    …}
>
> @form(routes.ProductMilestones.submitEdit(productReleaseId), 'id -> "submitMilestoneEditForm") {   
>
>     @*Here is the problem, when the form has an error I can not access milestoneList using get in the for loop*@
>     @for((milestone, index) <- milestoneFormSet.get.milestoneList.zipWithIndex) {
>         @milestoneFields(milestone, index)    
>     }
>
> }
> ```

Controller:

> ```
> public static Result submitEdit(Long productReleaseId) {
>   Form<MilestoneSet> filledForm = form(MilestoneSet.class).bindFromRequest();
>   if (filledForm.hasErrors()) {       
>     return badRequest(views.html.milestonesEdit.render(filledForm,
>     productReleaseId));
>   } else {
>     MilestoneSet newMilestoneSet = filledForm.get();
>     //...update code
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The get method trigger the validation so you can't use it in the view, you can pass the set to view with another variable.

Comment: Thanks that helped, I just used a different variable to iterate through the fields. But I think there has to be a better way to do this, because errors are still not displayed properly. As soon as I have a good solution I will update my quest.